# Postgres configuration for better performance

Tags: postgresql

We have done a PostreSql database Based ERP project. I have 32 GB RAM Windows Server 2012 R2 system. Out of 32 GB, I have used 8 GB for JVM and assuming 4 GB for OS, I have tried to tune the postgres with 20 GB RAM.
I have find out the configuration from the below link:
https://www.pgconfig.org/#/tuning?total_ram=20&max_connections=300&environment_name=OLTP&pg_version=9.2&os_type=Windows&arch=x86-64&share_link=true

But the performance goes down after the change. What could be the reason. As I am less knowledge in the postgres server maintenance, if anything more required for you to assess/answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres configuration depends on your version, OS and application type. I know only one good PostgreSQL tuner it's [pgtune.leopard.in.ua](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/). I used it to configure my Postgres on first time.

But don't think that is tuner solve all your problem at once, it's not a silver bullet. You should tune it for your application.